# Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component error

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm working on an app right now, and I'm getting an error that says "Text strings must be rendered within a Text> component." I've made this mistake before by just eliminating an unwanted character or word. But there is nothing wrong with this code. The code is as follows: (Go to the Itemadd section and try it out on your phone or simulator.) https://snack.expo.dev/@therealsneh/justexpire

If the error doesn't show, try adding to the code, like a text tag or something, then the error will come again

Comment: I don't get any error. Sure it wasn't just some cached files?

Comment: I didn't get any errors either.

Comment: Yes I am no longer getting the error, but when I add something new, like, let's say a text tag, it shows the error.